# How to setup IIS to perform basic http authentication against MS SQL database?

Tags: iis, .net, web.config

how to setup IIS to perform basic http authentication against MS SQL database (and not to use Windows domain)

The existing WS-Federated security is mapped to MS SQL database. We'd like to migrate to basic http authentication since it's simpler to users. However, I didn't found the way how to configure IIS to delegate to MS database.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is running in impersonate mode, with basic auth, I believe you could do this by telling your connection string to use the trusted connection, which means pass the credentials along.

impersonation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292118(v=vs.71).aspx

trusted connection: *Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;*
see http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008